# Difference between public {get; set} and programming getters and setters

Tags: c#, encapsulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Difference between Property and Variable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp)

I started working with C# a few weeks ago, and this is something that has really been bugging me. C# allows these so-called 'magic' getters and setters, also known as 'syntactical sugar'. So, I can do something like this:

`public int myInt { get; set; }`

But from an encapsulation standpoint, this is pointless. For one, the data member is **public**, and I can get/set it using the dot operator. However, if I do this:

`private int myInt { get; set; }`

I can't access it at all, as `myInt is inaccessible due to protection level`. What is this *actually* doing? I thought this was supposed to be an easy way to accomplish data encapsulation, so I wouldn't have to do this:

```
private int myInt;
public void setMyInt(int i) { myInt = i; }
public int getMyInt() { return myInt; }
```

But it's not. As near as I can tell, I'm just making these variables public. I thought maybe I would be able to do something like

`public int myInt { get; }`

So the client could `get` it, but not `set` it, but no, public access is still allowed. So what gives?

**EDIT**
I'm not trying to do anything specific, I just want to understand how this actually works. To clarify:

Making the variable `public` doesn't accomplish encapsulation, especially when I can access it with the dot operator. Writing getters and setters for a `private` variable allows you to make changes to the variable, but gives you greater control over how that actually happens.

Comment: This question has already been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Zak, that's what I was looking for. Please feel free to vote to close as dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose is that you maintain encapsulation through future modification.

If you initially write your class using automatic getters and setters:

```
public int Count { get; set; }
```

Then it'll maintain precisely the same external interface if you then change it to

```
public int Count {
    get { /* very complicated logic */ }
    set { /* even more complicated logic */ }
}
```

The automatic ones are just to help you with the simple properties at first.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to write

```
public int MyInt { get; private set; }
```

**EDIT**: The point of auto-implemented properties is not to provide additional encapsulation, but to avoid fields.
If you make a class with a public field (`publit int MyInt;`), and someone uses that field, you cannot change it to a property later, or you'll break any compiled assemblies that use it.

Using an auto-property gives you the same simplicity and concision as a field, but allow you to later replace it with a full-blown property (containing additional logic) without breaking anything.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand what's actually going on here, I'm not trying to do anything specific.

Comment: What precisely don't you understand?

Comment: I'd say the point of auto-implemented properties is primarily to just reduce the amount of boilerplate code you need to write for a trivial property.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes.  I meant as opposed to fields, which I suspect is what the OP meant.

Comment: In some instances, making the getter private and the setter public might sense as well. I have found this a useful idiom for dependency injection. There is no way to express this with public field.

Answer (score 6):

This "magic" getters and setters as you call them, actually end up creating methods just like you would do in Java. So Encapsulation `is` maintained just that with a cleaner look, IMO.

The properties themselves, even though declared as `public int Property {get;set;}` for example, actually have a backing field and a `getter` and a `setter` method.

See this contrived example:

```
class A
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

Now when you do something like:

```
A a = new A();
a.ID=5;
```

The IL code generated looks like this:

```
A.get_ID:    //getter method
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+A.<ID>k__BackingField 
IL_0006:  ret         

A.set_ID:   //setter method
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+A.<ID>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret
```

So yes, doing `a.ID=5`; *looks* like it's accessing directly a member variable but it's actually calling a method; in this case, the `set_ID` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are just making it public - if you want to specify private set, you can do something like this:

```
   int myInt { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I agree with SLaks - C# naming standards state that it should be MyInt, not myInt :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, which is very useful:

public int myInt { get; private set; }