# C# structures/classes/lists index

Tags: c#, list, class, struct, indexing

I'm currently learning C# and I was asked to make a game like monopoly on C and another version on C#. But there's some stuff I don't really understand on C# mainly because it's an object oriented language. So the question is, to manage the players I created a struct on the C version.

```
typedef struct regist
{
int number;
char name[50];
int money;
int position;
int inGame;
} Player;

Player players[8];
```

and to get any data of the struct I just do:

```
players[5].name = "Joe";
```

Now, my problem with C# is I managed to create the "struct". First I created a struct. Then I tried to make it with a list of structs. Then I just decided to make new instances of a class for every player. I was told it was the best way so I did it. So I have on my player class:

```
public class Players
{
 int number;
 string name;
 int money;
 int position;
 bool inGame;
 }
```

and on my form1:

private void newGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setNames();
            getNames();
        }

```
    public void setNames()
    {
        Players player1 = new Players();
        player1.name= textBox1.Text;
        Players player2 = new Players();
        player2.name = textBox2.Text;
        Players player3 = new Players();
        player3.name = textBox3.Text;
        Players player4 = new Players();
        player4.name = textBox4.Text;
    }
```

now what I don't know how to do is:

```
    public string getNames(){
        return Players[2].name;
    }
```

How can I achieve this? I also tried with lists but it wouldn't let me do it the way I wanted and also, I want to be able to use this same instances in others classes, I hope that is possible...
Thank you.

Comment: What was the issue when you tried to use lists?

Comment: Don't use `char` arrays.

Comment: Please show what you tried with lists. Because that's one of the bests ways to go. And by the way your final snippet won't work because a char array is not a string and your field is private by default.

Comment: what getNames should do? You are creating a class which is good, and creating multiple instances of it by calling new operator, which is also good. However there is a little typo in your example code: 
player2.name...  <=>   jogador2.name = textBox2.Text;

Also change class name from Players to Player so its correctly named.

Comment: @MPT Did you look at your C# code snippet? You have a char array in your class. And all those fields are private.

Comment: @Mino I'm sorry, it's fixed now, the typo was because I changed the code was in portuguese (jogadores) and i changed it to english (players) and forgot to change those :p

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Oh, I got it now...just a typo, because to post on the forum I copied from the C part, it's of course a string in my code, though :)

Comment: I posted the list code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a `List<Players>`, you need to actually add your intances to the list.Then you can index as you expect:

```
private List<Players> allPlayers = new List<Players>();

public void setNames()
{
    Players player1 = new Players();
    player1.name= textBox1.Text;
    Players player2 = new Players();
    player2.name = textBox2.Text;
    Players player3 = new Players();
    player3.name = textBox3.Text;
    Players player4 = new Players();
    player4.name = textBox4.Text;

    allPlayers.Add(player1);
    allPlayers.Add(player2);
    allPlayers.Add(player3);
    allPlayers.Add(player4);
}
```

Now you can access it as `allPlayers[2]` or whatever other index, in your other code.

A style note, your class should be named `Player` not `Players`. A `Player` is an object, `Players` indicates a collection property of `Player` objects.

Comment: yes, I get that and thank you but my question is, how can I then do that allPlayers[2] from within other classes? do I have to instantiate a new instance of the class that code is in?

Comment: @MPT No, you would need to pass the `allPlayers` list to that object, either on the class's constructor or as a parameter to one of the methods.

Comment: Presumably you know how parameters work, so your other class would have a method, say the constructor, that accepts a `List<Players>`, ie: `public MyOtherClass(List<Players> players)`. It would then probably store that reference off in a private variable, that the classes methods could then access. Objects are always passed **as** a reference (like a pointer) in C#, so both your variable and the other classes variable will point to the same object.

Comment: @MPT Not a problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

While Creating class use properties

```
public class Players
{
    public int number{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public int money{get;set;}
    public int position { get; set; }
    public bool inGame { get; set; }

    public string getNames(){
    return name;
    }
}
```

and while creating its objects

```
public  Players[] p = new Players[5];
```

and assignment can be done

```
p[0].name = textBox1.Text;
p[1].name = textBox2.Text;
p[2].name = textBox3.Text;
p[3].name = textBox4.Text;
p[4].name = textBox5.Text;
```

now if from any place of object p is accessible the  for sure you can

```
 p[2].getNames();
```

do this.

OR

use List

```
List<Players> pList = new List<Players>();
Players p1 = new Players();
p1.name="abc";
pList.add(p1);
Players p2 = new Players();
p2.name="xyz";
pList.add(p2);
```

and again if pList is accessible then

```
public string getNames(){
return pList[0].name;
}
```

Comment: when I use the return it says "index out of range", but if I put an messageBox.Show it works ok, why?

Comment: do one thing create a function getName inside the class and call using p[2].getName(); Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp

Comment: Arrays start at index 0, you might want to fix that.