# Can we initialize an array if we use it with a structure object? | C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

As we know that a simple array can be initialized like this for example, `int [] TestArray = {1,2,3,4}`, but how about if we use an array with a structure object and we want to initialize it?

I know that we can access the structure object array like this for example,

Suppose `struct Automobile` is our structure and we have field in it such as `public int year` , `public string model` and we create an array structure object for example, `Automobile [] Car = new Automobile();` so we can access the element of a structure array object and give it a value if we use it with structure field for example, `Car[2].year = "2016"`and then can display it in for example,

```
MessageBox.Show(Car[2].year.ToString());
```

But what if we want our structure array object to having initial values like we have it in normal array initialization as written in the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var auto = new[]
        {
            new Automobile {year = 1984, model = "charger"},
            new Automobile {year = 1985, model = "challenger"},
            new Automobile {year = 1984, model = "hemicuda"}
        };
```

`var auto = new[]` is shorthand for `Automobile[] auto = new Automobile[]` which you can use instead if you're more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

Let the Structure be defined as like this:

```
public struct Automobile
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create the array of this structure variables like the following:

```
Automobile[] AutomobileList = new Automobile[] { 
                               new Automobile() {Year=2015,model="Some model1" },
                               new Automobile() {Year=2014,model="Some model2" },
                               new Automobile() {Year=2013,model="Some model3" }};
```

Similar way you can define a list too;

```
List<Automobile> AutomobileList = new List<Automobile>() { 
                                   new Automobile() {Year=2015,model="Some model1" },
                                   new Automobile() {Year=2014,model="Some model2" },
                                   new Automobile() {Year=2013,model="Some model3" }};
```

Comment: What is  `get; set` and why you used it when it worked without it as well? Can you share your knowledge with us?

Comment: @GhostRider - Have you not seen `get; set;` before?

Comment: That are used to define Properties, You can use this Thread to understand the [Difference between Variables and properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp)