# Can we set the properties of an Object of a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `class Program` which have an object of `class c2` as shown in an example below

```
class c2{
    public string Name;
    public int RollNo;
    public c2(string Name , int RollNo){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.RollNo = RollNo;
    }

    private c2 obj1;
    public c2 obj{
        get
        {
            return obj1;
        }
        set{
            obj1=value;
        }
    }
    public void show(){
         Console.WriteLine(""+obj1.Name+" "+obj1.RollNo);
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        c2 objNew = new c2("Test",12);
        objNew.obj = objNew;
        objNew.show();

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Test 12

In the above code `class c2` has a private reference `obj1` and which is `get` `set` by an object obj from `class program`.How value is assigned to obj and obj1 as they are not physically existed as memory is not assigned to them with the help of `new` operator.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What are 'the properties of an object of a class'?

Comment: Check this one, can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp

Comment: A property is a member of an instance of a class (unless it is `static`). The same appiles for fields and methods. A property has nothing to do with a field, in particular it is no extension of the latter.

Comment: var c1Obj = new C1();
c1Obj.obj = new C2();
//Assuming C2 has a string property called propVal
c1Obj.obj.propVal = "new value"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, for example

```
class C1{
     public C2 Obj {get;set;}
}

class C2{}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        C2 prop1 = c1.Obj;
        c1.Obj = new C2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can be get or set, if they are declared that way.

Readonly property: `public C2 obj {get;}`

Write and read property `public C2 obj {get;set;}`

You can do also fancy things with properties like `public C2 obj {get;private set;}` or add custom validation logic in the setter method.

You got a sample in setting a property in oleksii's answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can like this

```
class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public CarManufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

Car car = new Car();
car.Name = "Corvette";
car.Color = Color.Yellow;
car.Manufacturer = new CarManufacturer();
car.Manufacturer.Name = "Chevrolet";
car.Manufacturer.Country = "USA";
```

also you can intilize it like this

```
Car car = new Car { 
                Name = "Chevrolet Corvette", 
                Color = Color.Yellow, 
                Manufacturer = new CarManufacturer { 
                    Name = "Chevrolet", 
                    Country = "USA" 
                } 
            };
```