# List with a custom type

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I want to say that I am learning the language with simple coding.

If I create an object `ResourceTemplate` as

```
public class ResourceTemplate
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}
```

And then made

```
List<ResourceTemplate> resource = new List<ResourceTemplate>();
```

That resource will be a list with the structure from `ResourceTemplate`.
If that's so, **why I can not use** `resource.Add("product", 500);?`

The compiler says that:

> it can't do an overload with the .Add() function

.

Comment: Why you think you can do so?

Comment: Why you not can't -> Have a look at [MSDN List<T>.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) document.

Comment: because ´Add()´ takes only object as param

Comment: as if i did a custom function that receives different parameters.

Comment: you are trying to add separately a string and then a number in your list of Things (ResourceTemplate) . You have to tell the C# compiler that you want to make a Thing out of your string and number, and then add this object to the list.

Comment: Do you think this is C++ with `emplace_back`?

Comment: Please use [public properties, not public fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4142867/107625).

Comment: As i stated in the question i am still learning the language. I come from C++ (basic level from self taught)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>.Add` expects an instance of the specified type, not a list of arguments that would create such a type.

For example (using the object initializer syntax):

```
resource.Add(new ResourceTemplate {Name = "product", Value = 500});
```

You can also use the collection initializer syntax additionally:

```
var resource = new List<ResourceTemplate>() {{Name = "product", Value = 500}};
```

Comment: So in order to "overload" that .Add function i can instanciate my ResourceTemplate class? A bit confusing, i will dig on that.

Answer (score 6):

You should create a new [instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) of the class:

```
resource.Add(new ResourceTemplate {Name = "product", Value = 500});
```

Or like this:

```
ResourceTemplate resourceTemplate = new ResourceTemplate
{
    Name = "product",
    Value = 500
};
resource.Add(resourceTemplate);
```

However by adding a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) to your class like this:

```
public class ResourceTemplate
{
    public ResourceTemplate(string name, int value)
    {
         Name = name;
         Value = value;
    }
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}
```

You can then:

```
resource.Add(new ResourceTemplate("product", 500 ));
```

Also I'd suggest that you use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of public fields:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, mate!

Answer (score 1):

By default: `resource.Add` can only accept a `ResourceTemplate` as parameter.

The correct syntax must be:

```
var resourceTemplate = new ResourceTemplate 
{
    Name = "product",
    Price = 500,
};

resource.Add(resourceTemplate);
```

You can't do that because there is no version of `Add` that can accept a string and an integer and convert to an unknown `ResourceTemplate` structure.

In order to add an overload of `Add` you can create an extension method:

```
public static class ListExtensions 
{
    public static void Add(this List<ResourceTemplate> list, string name, string price)
    {
        var resourceTemplate = new ResourceTemplate 
        {
            Name = name,
            Price = price,
        };

        list.Add(resourceTemplate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive updated the answer in case you need to overload the Add method

Comment: Yeah that's what i wanted because i will have some sort of DataBase to load up a bunch of "Resources" into it and i need a fast method. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Could you exaplain me a bit this part? this List<ResourceTemplate> list. I know what is this and the like but i need to understand the concept.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods - it's called extension method. It adds a new method to an existing class

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection base structure.

```
public class ResourceTemplate
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}
public class ResourceTemplateList : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
    public void Add(string name, int value)
    {
        this.List.Add(new ResourceTemplate { Name = name, Value = value });
    }
}
```

Then, you can add class members to the list.

```
ResourceTemplateList r_templates = new ResourceTemplateList();

r_templates.Add("product", 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

So far those are the main concepts (and solution) that i solved in this question:

```
//Declarations of Lists
public List<ResourceTemplate> stockpile = new List<ResourceTemplate>();

//We pass to the obj a name and creates the obj 
//with the name and a stockpile
public NationBuilder(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            stockpile = new List<ResourceTemplate>();
        }

//Add resources to the stockpile
public void AddResource(string itemName, int quantity,  float value)
    {
        //We can add resources into the stockpile with LINQ
        stockpile.Add(new ResourceTemplate 
        {
            Name = itemName, Quantity = quantity, Value = value
        });
    }
```

The output of this solution is this data structure:

```
- nation
   - Name
   - Stockpile
     -[0] <-Here
        - Name "resourceName"
        - Quantity "quantity"
        - Value "value"
```

Here: I would like to have instead of indexing via in, to index via a Name.
Instead of

```
[0] -> [Coal]
         - Quantity
         - Value
```

Otherwise the handler that will manage the stockpiles will need to know beforehand where each resource will be located.

Comment: Thank you all who collaborated (and edited my mistakes)